# jQuery Cycle Plugin Previous/Next

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Just wondering when using the jQuery Cycle plugin if for the next/prev buttons, it can be configured so that clicking the next button would slide right, and clicking prev would slide left.

Thanks for your help.
Dave

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ack!

Forget that, just found the answer [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/scrollhv.html) for anyone else who would like to know.

Comment: Good question and answer!, Its helpful for me

Comment: There is nothing wrong than having a question and answering it yourself. I was using "scrollLeft" and was in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager11.html) for the cycle plugin which does exactly what you want and includes a pager.  The key is to use the 'scrollHorz' effect.